# Weld 3.8.1 CDI 2.0 on Tomcat 9

Tags: tomcat, cdi, java-ee-7, weld

I followed this [tutorial](https://balusc.omnifaces.org/2013/10/how-to-install-cdi-in-tomcat.html) to setup weld on tomcat. I'm using Netbeans 12 IDE and project is web application with ant. Running tomcat is 9.0.50. To my project I added dependency `weld-servlet-shaded-3.1.8.Final`. Then created simple bean:

```
package com.example.app;

import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean
public class SomeObject {
    
    public String sayHello(){
        return "heloo from some object :)";
    } 
}
```

This is simple web service which is using defined bean:

```
package com.example.app;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;

@WebService(serviceName = "MyService")
public class MyService {

    @Inject
    private SomeObject object;

    @WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
    public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt) {
        return "Hello " + object.sayHello() + " !";
    }
}
```

**WEB-INF/beans.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                           http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_2_0.xsd"
       version="2.0"
       bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

**WEB-INF/web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyService</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyService</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/MyService</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

**META-INF/context.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/WebAppJAXWS">
    <Resource name="BeanManager" 
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager"
        factory="org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory" />
</Context>
```

Weld is successfully started by tomcat:

```
07-Sep-2021 10:48:33.429 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-60] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying deployment descriptor [C:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.50\conf\Catalina\localhost\WebAppJAXWS.xml]
07-Sep-2021 10:48:33.430 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-60] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor The path attribute with value [/WebAppJAXWS] in deployment descriptor [C:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.50\conf\Catalina\localhost\WebAppJAXWS.xml] has been ignored
07-Sep-2021 10:48:34.658 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-60] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
07-Sep-2021 10:48:34.678 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-60] org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.EnhancedListener.onStartup WELD-ENV-001008: Initialize Weld using ServletContainerInitializer
07-Sep-2021 10:48:34.706 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-60] org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.<clinit> WELD-000900: 3.1.8 (Final)
07-Sep-2021 10:48:34.958 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-60] org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.startContainer WELD-000101: Transactional services not available. Injection of @Inject UserTransaction not available. Transactional observers will be invoked synchronously.
07-Sep-2021 10:48:35.193 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-60] org.jboss.weld.environment.tomcat.TomcatContainer.initialize WELD-ENV-001100: Tomcat 7+ detected, CDI injection will be available in Servlets, Filters and Listeners.
07-Sep-2021 10:48:35.349 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-60] com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized WSSERVLET12: JAX-WS context listener initializing
07-Sep-2021 10:48:36.620 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-60] com.sun.xml.ws.server.MonitorBase.createRoot Metro monitoring rootname successfully set to: com.sun.metro:pp=/,type=WSEndpoint,name=/WebAppJAXWS-MyService-MyServicePort
07-Sep-2021 10:48:36.771 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-60] com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.<init> WSSERVLET14: JAX-WS servlet initializing
07-Sep-2021 10:48:36.786 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-60] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of deployment descriptor [C:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.50\conf\Catalina\localhost\WebAppJAXWS.xml] has finished in [3,356] ms
```

When I call my web method exception is returned that injected object is null:

```
07-Sep-2021 10:52:00.218 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-63] com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler.invoke null
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.app.MyService.hello(MyService.java:16)
...
```

What might be wrong in this configuration?

Comment: I think the problem is that your setup does not support injection into web services. (Despite the fact that you declare `MyService` as a servlet in web.xml, apparently it is NOT a real servlet for Weld.) What library are you using for JAX-WS? Maybe that library has some hints on how to support CDI.